# Maven provided scope and Java classloader

Tags: maven, classpath, classloader

I have a misunderstanding of how to use maven `provided` scope and the Java classloader.

Say I have a class, `MyClass`, and this class has a `serialize()` method that takes an enum that describes what JSON library to use when serializing.

One of these JSON libraries is internal, and included in the JAR that I distribute for MyClass. Simple.

The other JSON library is a 3rd party library that I want to force the user to provide. Thus, I put it under `<scope>provided</scope>` in my pom.

Everything works for me during tests, but when I try to use my own library from the outside without the 3rd party JSON library in my classpath, I get `ClassNotFoundException`s, **even though I'm not making a call to `serialize()` at all.**

I was under the assumption that classes would only be loaded 'as-needed', and since I'm not making a call to `serialize()`, I shouldn't have any runtime problems. Am I wrong? Is there no way to achieve what I am getting at here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I had a static initializer that was making a call to the 3rd party JSON library which was causing the issue.

I do expect a class not found, if I'm a user of the api and not providing the 3rd party JAR. However, my concern was that I wasn't making any calls to cause the JAR to be needed. Static initializer threw me off.

Answer (score 0):

Provided scope basically means that it is available at runtime. Generally not the case for 3rd party libraries such as JSON. Since you are taking care of packaging your own jar, you need to include all required classes there. Normally Maven users use something like Maven Assembly Plugin to let Maven pack together required dependencies and create a single jar.

Answer (score 0):

'provided' implies that it will be provided *later*, at runtime, so don't include it in dependencies (e.g. when packaging the application into a WAR or JAR)

A good example of when this is used - when compiling against an API, say the Java EE API, where you need the jar at compile time, but you don't need to include it in the WAR file, since the server will have those classes by definition.

you need the servlet classes to compile against, but your WAR file will always be used in a context where the container already has it on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your assumption about loading classes when needed is in general correct, however it works pretty different than you think. Class is loaded by a classloader when needed along with all classes it references. It happens recursively. So, when you first time use `MyClass`, classloader tries to load this 3rd party JSON lib classes that are referenced. Kind of run-time class loading you're talking about is possible by using Java reflection capability. It is pretty different thing however, as you probably already know.

Second thing is `provided` scope in Maven. It works just like `compile`, but the dependency doesn't "go" with an artifact. That means this dependency is available at compile-time and for test execution (it is then provided by Maven). However, it wouldn't be visible as the artifact's transitive dependency (by artifacts that depend on this one). So it wouldn't be copied to the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of WAR that depends on your artifact, nor it would be assembled by `jar-with-dependencies` descriptor of `maven-assembly-plugin`. There is a strong assumption here, that your artifact's user provides this dependency himself, so it is his business here to provide these classes into classpath. Typically, it is used on Java EE application servers, where some platform-related dependencies are always available, like Servlet API, JPA, EJB or JMS. If your application uses these APIs, then you depend on them with `provided` scope.

So at the end, in your case, you should use defaut, `compile` scope, because this dependency is really needed.